# iPhone 6/6+ layout - views won't touch each other/hidden margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder

I have 4 "buttons" (black) that has the following constraints:

- same width to superview height, multiplier 0.4 (using superview height to create perfect square)
- same height to superview height, multiplier 0.4
- trailing/trailing/top/bottom to "ColDiv" and"RowDiv" (red), 0 constant, 1 multiplier

My problem is, the buttons don't "touch" the dividers on iPhone 6/6+. They always have a "hidden" margin to them. It works as I want on smaller screens (iPhone 4s).

Anyone know why this happens?

And no, I don't have the "Constrain to margins" checked on any constraints.

It looks like this:

[image]

UPDATE:

When I set the width and height's multiplier to 0.3 (making the buttons smaller), the margins also get small. So the "hidden" margin's size is relative to the button's size. This could be a workaround, but that would mean smaller buttons, which is not a good thing for this project.

Comment: Thanks for the image @remus

Answer (score 0):

0.4 + 0.4 = 0.8. Your margin is the 0.2 difference you haven't accounted for.

Change your widths and heights to 0.5 and you should be good.

Comment: I tested just now, and it only made the "hidden" margins bigger. I imagine it was because the "buttons"became bigger. Thanks though!

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your constraints?

Comment: Those are upper left button's constraints. Y align/axis currently not set to RowDiv. Testing x axis for now.

Comment: I think part of it is that you need to bind leading to leading and trailing to trailing. Adding a center Y in there also confuses things.

Comment: That center Y is just another test. It was set to "bottom to RowDiv, 0" before. Also same behaviour.

Comment: If you align button's leading to ColDiv's leading, that would put the button to the right of ColDiv, right? This button should be on the upper left.

Comment: Assign top left's leading/ to parent leading/top. Top right's trailing/top to parent trailing/top. Bottom left's leading/bottom to parent leading/bottom. Bottom right's trailing/bottom to parent trailing/bottom.

Comment: Just tested, it only pulls the button (top left) to .. top left.